# I need show cases 1 and 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Prove that :

If lim inf$s_n$ = lim sup$s_n$ ,
then lim $s_n$ is defined and lim $s_n$ = lim inf$s_n$ = lim sup$s_n$

> case(1) lim inf$s_n$ = lim sup$s_n$ = +∞ then lim $s_n$ = +∞.
>
> case (2) if lim inf$s_n$ = lim sup$s_n$  = −∞  then  lim $s_n$  = −∞. case(3)
>
> case(3) Suppose that lim inf $s_n$ = lim sup $s_n$ = $s$ where $s$ is a real number. We need to prove lim $s_n$ = $s$. Let $ε > 0$ Since $s$ = lim vN there exists a positive integer $N_0$ such that
> $|s−sup{s_n :n>N_0}|$<ε. Thus sup${s_n :n>N_0}$<$s+ε$ , so
> $s_n$ <$s+ε$ for all n>$N_0$. (1) Similarly, there exists $N_1$ such that $|s − inf {s_n : n > N_1 }| $ < ε,
> hence inf${s_n:n>N_1}$ >$s−ε$, hence
> $s_n$ >$s−ε$ forall $n>N_1$. (2)
> From (1) and (2) we conclude
> $s−ε$<$s_n$<$s+ε $ for n>max${N_0,N_1}$ ,
> equivalently
> $|s_n − s| $ < $ε$ for n > max${N_0,N_1}$. This proves lim $s_n$ = $s$ as desired.

Comment: Unreadable. Please format with $\LaTeX$. | We need to know your effort and/or mathematics level so we can write an answer properly.

Comment: Make explicit the points you don't understand.

Comment: My edit was to delete one dollar-sign. It would be better  to put dollar-signs only before the very beginning and after the very end of each formula. Use \sup and \max and \lim and \infty  between dollar-signs. And don't omit the space immediately after each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hint

Indefinite limits can be vaguely defined using a phrase "For however large $K$ there exists $\varepsilon$ such that any values of $s_n$ are higher than $K$.", hence no need to consider supremum for case (1) and infimum for case (2).

I hope I did not spoil the fun playing around with the $\varepsilon$'s, it is a great exercise.